# I installed Mythbuntu 14.04 and can't get my remote to work

Tags: 14.04, remote, lirc

I try to restart lirc and I get the following error:

```
find: `/sys/class/rc/*/': No such file or directory
 * Stopping remote control daemon(s): LIRC                               [ OK ] 
 * Loading LIRC modules                                                  [ OK ] 
find: `/sys/class/rc/*/': No such file or directory
 * Starting remote control daemon(s) :                                   [ OK ]
```

I tried typing in irw to see if I get anything and I get absolutely nothing

**here is the hardware info**

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=147a Product=e031 Version=0111
N: Name="Formosa21 IR603 HID MCE"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3
B: PROP=0
B: EV=10001f
B: KEY=4837fff072ff32d bf54444600000000 1 20f908b17c000 677bfad9415fed e09effdf01cfffff fffffffffffffffe
B: REL=40
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10
```

**here is the lsusb output**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 147a:e031 Formosa Industrial Computing, Inc.
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I just cant seem to get it to work. My system is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out to be related to USB3 ports using xhci. You have a couple of options:

1. Disable xhci in the BIOS if possible, and try to see if irw
   responds.
2. Use ir-keytable instead of LIRC.

For option 2:

```
% sudo apt-get purge lirc
```

## Install ir-keytable

```
% sudo apt-get install ir-keytable
```

## Find the device/eventID for your remote:

```
% ir-keytable
```

You’ll get an output that looks like this with an eventID for your IR transceiver:

```
Found /sys/class/rc/rc1/ (/dev/input/event10) with:
Driver mceusb, table rc-rc6-mce
Supported protocols: NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC other 
Enabled protocols: NEC RC-5 RC-6 JVC SONY SANYO LIRC other 
Name: Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared 
bus: 3, vendor/product: 147a:e03e, version: 0x1001
Repeat delay = 500 ms, repeat period = 125 ms
```

Test the remote keypresses using the eventID from the previous step.  This is similar to using “irw” with lirc.  This is for pressing the “OK” key once on the remote.

```
% sudo ir-keytabe --test --device=/dev/input/event10
```

You should get an output that looks like the one below:

```
 1416166547.998594: event type EV_MSC(0x04): scancode = 0x800f0422
 1416166547.998594: event type EV_KEY(0x01) key_down: KEY_OK(0x0001)
 1416166547.998594: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
 1416166548.104565: event type EV_MSC(0x04): scancode = 0x800f0422
 1416166548.104565: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
 1416166548.353099: event type EV_KEY(0x01) key_up: KEY_OK(0x0001)
 1416166548.353099: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
```

If that works, you know that the keypresses are being recognized by your system. Beyond that point, you can map the keys you want for your remote.  I was able to get this part to work today with my Formosa mceusb IR xcvr.  Let me know if you need more information down this path.